# How to create a DataView RowFilter that can filter if the input string is a substring of the string in the desired column

Tags: c#, regex, string, dataview, rowfilter

I would like to create a `DataView RowFilter` that can filter if
the input string is a substring of the string in the column. For example, if the datatable `dt` has the column `"Name"`, with the string values `"Mary"` in one row and `"John"` in the other. I want to a user to be able to type `"ary"` in a searchbox and the returned row is the one containing `"Mary"`.  Needless to say

```
dv.RowFilter = "Name = 'Mary'"
```

Will only return an exact match.  I also want it such that if the input string is empty it returns all rows.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Per this [link](http://www.csharp-examples.net/dataview-rowfilter/), you can use the `LIKE` comparison operator and the `*` wildcard. The following statement would return all rows where the Name column includes the value "Mary":

```
dv.RowFilter = "Name LIKE '*Mary*'"
```

Note, if the value were blank, the satement would be `"Name LIKE '**'"`, which would return all rows so this satisfies your other condition.

Comment: Thanks it worked!!! Also I didn't need to put the `"Name LIKE '**'"` criteria as  it automatically returned all the rows when the searchtextbox was blank!!!